# Changing options tag in view.phtml for configurable

Tags: template, custom-options, configurable-product

what I need is to change the "select" and "option" tag to simple div or better to "ul" and "li".

This has to be in the view.phtml for configurable as already specified in the subject.
I know the file to edit are the js/varien/configurable.js, or better just the  template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml in my styled them,

but can´t achieve it anyhow.
Any guess?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you can't achieve it? What have you tried and what is the outcome?

Answer (score 2):

You can give [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) a try. It does (almost) what you need (and much more).

Read full feature list [here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/README.md):

It does not change the selects to `ul` and `li` elements but it changes them to labels with the text.

But you can change the format if you want at [this line](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/blob/master/js/easylife_switcher/product.js#L148). You may need to change the css also if you change the labels to other elements.